# Erro: Não foi possível processar o tipo 'xxx[]' porque ele não possui qualquer mapeamento conhecido à camada de valor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, session, lista

Na controller tenho minha sessão construída.

```
public const string ListaPermissao_SessionName = "ListaPermissao";

private List<ListaPermissao> ListaPermissaoEnvio
{
    get
    {
        if (Session[ListaPermissao_SessionName] == null)
            Session[ListaPermissao_SessionName] = new List<ListaPermissao>();
        return (List<ListaPermissao>)Session[ListaPermissao_SessionName];
    }
    set
    {
        Session[ListaPermissao_SessionName] = (List<ListaPermissao>)value;
    }
}
```

Classe ListaPermissao:

```
public class ListaPermissao
{
    public ListaPermissao()
    {
        this.editado = false;
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool value { get; set; }
    public bool editado { get; set; }
}
```

Em determinado momento preciso recuperar uma lista de outros objetos, porém para validar o atributo @checked preciso consultar essa lista/sessão.

```
var employees = from e in this.context.PermissaoGrupo.Where(x => x.IdGrupo == idGrupo && x.Ativo)
                where (id.HasValue ? e.Permissao.IdPermissaoPai == id : e.Permissao.IdPermissaoPai == null)
                        select new
                        {
                            id = e.IdPermissao,
                            text = e.Permissao.Descricao,
                            hasChildren = e.Permissao.Permissao1.Any(),
                            expanded = e.Permissao.Permissao1.Any(),
                            ord = e.Permissao.Ordem,
                            @checked = (idUsuario != 0 ? ListaPermissaoEnvio.Any(x => x.id == e.IdPermissaoGrupo && x.value) : false),
                            idPermissaoGrupo = e.IdPermissaoGrupo
                        };
```

É retornado o seguinte erro:

> Não foi possível processar o tipo 'ListaPermissao[]' porque ele não possui qualquer mapeamento conhecido à camada de valor.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de algumas tentativas consegui resolver apenas colocando .AsEnumerable() antes da consulta, só achei estranho que na forma que eu normalmente uso as consultas não deu certo...

Normalmente usaria:

```
context.PermissaoGrupo.Include(x => x.Permissao).AsEnumerable()
.Where(x => x.IdGrupo == idGrupo && x.Ativo && (id.HasValue ? x.Permissao.IdPermissaoPai == id : x.Permissao.IdPermissaoPai == null))
.Select(x => new
{
    id = x.IdPermissao,
    text = x.Permissao.Descricao,
    hasChildren = x.Permissao.Permissao1.Any(),
    expanded = x.Permissao.Permissao1.Any(),
    ord = x.Permissao.Ordem,
    @checked = (idUsuario != 0 ? ListaPermissaoEnvio.Any(z => z.id == x.IdPermissaoGrupo && z.value) : false),
    idPermissaoGrupo = x.IdPermissaoGrupo
});
```

Funcionou assim:

```
from x in this.context.PermissaoGrupo.Include(x => x.Permissao).AsEnumerable()
where (x.IdGrupo == idGrupo && x.Ativo && (id.HasValue ? x.Permissao.IdPermissaoPai == id : x.Permissao.IdPermissaoPai == null))
select new
{
    id = x.IdPermissao,
    text = x.Permissao.Descricao,
    hasChildren = x.Permissao.Permissao1.Any(),
    expanded = x.Permissao.Permissao1.Any(),
    ord = x.Permissao.Ordem,
    @checked = (idUsuario != 0 ? ListaPermissaoEnvio.Any(z => z.id == x.IdPermissaoGrupo && z.value) : false),
    idPermissaoGrupo = x.IdPermissaoGrupo
};
```

Se alguém souber o motivo e compartilhar conosco....